# Ember JS check if the model is already defined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Trying to define custom model in ember using

```
Ember.getOwner(this.store).register('model:custom-model', {
 customName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

While running the same component again, getting the following error saying the model is already defined.

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot re-register: 'model:custom-model', as it has already been resolved.`

How to check if the model is already defined?

Answer (score 1):

There is the `hasRegistration()` method which should help you, i.e.

`if (Ember.getOwner(this.store).hasRegistration('model:custom-model')) {...}`

https://api.emberjs.com/ember/4.3/classes/ApplicationInstance/methods/hasRegistration?anchor=hasRegistration

One thing though - you're using quite old version of Ember, so this answer might require some refinement, however this method exists at least in v2.18.